# Trigger a link remotely

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have this sidemenu and a form for logging out like so (default generated by mvc)
How can I make it so that when the user clicks in on the `<li>` element it will trigger that log out link?

And I was wondering if some inline Javascript or something could do the trick?

```
            <li id="log-out-li">
                @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" }))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Log out</a>
                }
            </li>
```

Comment: Why do you need a form for this (as opposed to just the link which redirects to the `LogOff()` method)?

Comment: I am just using the default, like how it came when i started my new project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd want to make an `<li>` clickable, but here you go...

```
document.getElementById('log-out-li').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit();
});
```

I'd advise just making your logoff page a simple GET and just hyperlink to it from a regular `<a href="..."` tag rather than an `li` though

Answer (score 0):

If you want to accomplish this using jQuery, you could do the following:

```
$("#log-out-li").click(function() {
  window.location.href = $("#ID_of_your_log-out_link").attr("href");
});
```

Essentially when you click the `li` element with the `#log-out-li` ID, it will execute the anonymous function that changes the location of the window to the href defined in your log-out link.

Resources:

[.click() | jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

[.attr() | jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)